# Starting with sawtooth xo transaction

Tags: hyperledger-sawtooth

I have setup Hyperledger Sawtooth on Docker,
I am trying to test sawtooth XO transactions with following commands

```
uname@uname:~/sawtooth$ docker exec -it sawtooth-shell-default bash
root@5279e5a413c1:/# xo create one
```

but I am getting following error

*Error: Failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:8008/batches: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8008): Max retries exceeded with url: /batches (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111]     Connection refused',))*

FYKI This commands works for me

From shell this gives me blocks

```
curl http://rest-api:8008/blocks
```

From my host this works as expected

```
curl http://localhost:8008/blocks
curl http://127.0.0.1:8008/blocks
```

What is wrong with this?

My yaml file is the default one, you can find it [here](https://pastebin.com/LELvnSSm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using docker you have to mention url to APIs this way

```
xo create one --url http://rest-api:8008
```

I found this after Ashish gave this hint at

https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/sawtooth

Comment: some articles shows -url which seems for older version

Comment: That was a mistake that may exist in older docs--use
 `--url` (with 2 dashes)